# Exclude an element with a specific attribute from jQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I am using this javascript to empty an input/textarea when focussed.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="text"],textarea').not('[readonly="readonly"]').addClass("idleField");
    $('input[type="text"],textarea').focus(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("idleField").addClass("focusField");
        if (this.value == this.defaultValue){
            this.value = '';
        }
        if(this.value != this.defaultValue){
            this.select();
        }
    });
    $('input[type="text"],textarea').blur(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("focusField").addClass("idleField");
        if ($.trim(this.value) == ''){
            this.value = (this.defaultValue ? this.defaultValue : '');
        }
    });
   });
```

I am looking for a way to exclude those `input` fields, which are set `readonly` via `readonly="readonly"`. I know I should be using `.not` (I guess), but I can not figure out how.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want all input elements that are writable (not readonly), you can use the following selector:

```
$("input:not([readonly])")
```

The parameter after [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) is the selector to match. [readonly] will match anything where readonly is set. Note that the following will not always work:

```
[readonly="readonly"]
```

As you could have both of these:

```
<input readonly type="text">
<input readonly="readonly" type="text">
```

You can also use the ":input" psuedo-selector instead of "input,textarea". See the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/).